# Angularjs - TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to create a contacts app with angularjs. I have created a file in the root directory of the project called server.js. Here is the code:

```
var express = require('express'),
app     = express();

app
    .use(express.static('./public'))
    .get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile('public/main.html');
    })
    .listen(3000);
```

When I go to localhost:3000, this is the error message that comes up.

> TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
>      at ServerResponse.sendFile (D:\Workspace\contacts\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:389:11)
>      at D:\Workspace\contacts\server.js:7:7
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Workspace\contacts\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>      at next (D:\Workspace\contacts\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:13)
>      at Route.dispatch (D:\Workspace\contacts\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:81:3)
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Workspace\contacts\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
>      at D:\Workspace\contacts\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:235:24
>      at Function.proto.process_params (D:\Workspace\contacts\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:313:12)
>      at D:\Workspace\contacts\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:229:12
>      at Function.match_layer (D:\Workspace\contacts\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:296:3)

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
var path = require('path');  

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public', 'main.html'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/main.html');
```

You have to specify an absolute path (starting with /)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that and the error message remains. Very frustrating!

Comment: Maybe beacause of the windows-filesystem... Log the output of __dirname - there is a chance you have to use windows-separators (__dirname + '\\public\\main.html')?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the path in your get('*') function to an absolute path:

```
res.sendfile('public/main.html');
```

You can use express' `__dirname` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you access the public directory relative to the current working directory.
Below changes should work in your case

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    path = require('path'),
    publicDir = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

app.use(express.static(publicDir))
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicDir, 'main.html'));
}).listen(3000);
```